# Change Bootstrap column class attribute based on screen size/media query

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am using Twitter's bootstrap and I have a problem. I am using the grid system and in my html have used the `col-lg-6` class to create a two different columns with equal width. See code below:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="row sameHeightCols">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="contentBlock">
                <h3>Header</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h3>Header2</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue I am having is that when it hits a certain screen size it breaks and some of the content in the left block disappears. This occurs when screen size is between `col-lg` and `col-md`. What I would like to to do is change the classes at a certain screen size so it changes to this.

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <div class="contentBlock">
      <h3>Header</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
     <h3>Header2</h3>
</div>
```

Is this possible in css with a media query? or do I need to use javascript? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have done a lot of research and cannot find a solution. Please also let me know if any further code/info is required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Paul Fitzgerald**, Hi there. Are you just wanting to change this from 6x6 when lg... to 9x3 at md ?

If so have a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xztpb8k7/1/embedded/result/)**.

Resize the window. I you do not want this to stack then let us know.

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-6 block1"><h2>Header 1</h2></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-6 block2"><h2>Header 2</h2></div>    
    </div>    
</div>
```

The screenshot below shows the change when resized from LG 6x6 to MD 9x3.

[image]

**Added to this post**

**Paul**, I think this is what you are wanting here, to have a new **media breakpoint** between **MD** and **LG**.

In the screenshot below I added text to show when it is using **LG** and **XLG** and **MD**.

[image: adding media breakpoints]

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/se7vsatL/embedded/result/)**.

Hope this gets you started with how you want this.

Comment: no i want to make the change somewhere in between ```col-lg``` and ```col-md```. When it gets to below ```min-width 1200px```  then I want to change the class as to what I mentioned in my question. Does it make sense what I am asking?

Comment: Hi Paul, Have a read of this [**Media Breakpoints**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) . There is not much difference between LG and MD. You can add your own media breakpoint if you want something like I think you are asking. But saying that, to reduce a column (2) like this you may want to re look at your overall design/layout here.

Comment: **Paul**, Have a look at my post above. I have added a new fiddle which has a media breakpoint between MD and LG. See how that works for you. Change the width to what you are looking for, I have it set to 1100px to 1200px.

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need `Java Script` you can use media query . but you are using bootstrap you don't need that [see this table](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)
it shows every class according to size of screen try to add multiple classes but every thing can not be appear on every screen size use these classes [[here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)] to hide on particular screen size. If you are trying to create to menu you will need bootstrap java script code and jQuery

Comment: so I have seen this... the issue is that it breaks in between ```col-lg``` and ```col-md```. So at this break point i want to change to the points above. Make sense?

Comment: did you see classes and corresponding screen width if it is lower than they will get stacked

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what that means. There is probably a gap in my knowledge

Comment: see in col-md class 970px min width if window is resized minimum to that pixel they will get arranged one above

Comment: if want to arrange them when window get resized use multiple class for both but same like md-6 for one and md-3 for other while for large screen size lg-6 and lg-6 on same elements or tags

Comment: do i need to change the bootstrap.css code? if not, would you be able to provide to the code in your answer so I can try and implement

Comment: just do this add a col class for large resolution <div class="col-lg-6"><div> <div class="col-lg-6"><div>

Comment: then add another class for lower resolution <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-9"><div> <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-3"><div>

Comment: if are trying to change resolution of classes go to bootstrap website and open customize tab scroll down there you will find Media queries breakpoints and change respective resolution download the file then you are good to go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83567/discussion-between-paul-fitzgerald-and-shubham-patel).